# Remove dictionary from list if it contains forbidden value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-3.10

I have a list of dictionaries:

```py
my_dicts = [
  {'name': 'aaa',
  'codename': 'bbbb',
  'type': 'cccc',
  'website': 'url1'},
  {'name': 'aaa2',
  'codename': 'bbbb2',
  'type': 'cccc2',
  'product_url': 'url2'},
  {'name': 'aaa2',
  'codename': 'bbbb2',
  'type': 'cccc2',
  'dop_url': 'url3'}
 ]
```

and a list:

```
my_list = ['url1', 'url3']
```

My goal is to have this output:

```py
my_dicts = [
  {'name': 'aaa2',
  'codename': 'bbbb2',
  'type': 'cccc2',
  'product_url': 'url2'}
 ]
```

I want to find the most efficient way to remove the dictionaries where any value of said dictionary is in a list.

I tried this, but I'm getting the following error: `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`.

```py
for url in my_list:
        for e in my_dicts:
            for key, value in e.items():
                if value == url:
                    del e[key]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `all()`, retaining only the dictionaries that do not have a key-value pair where the value appears in `my_list`:

```py
[item for item in my_dict if all(url not in item.values() for url in my_list)]
```

This outputs:

```py
[{'name': 'aaa2', 'codename': 'bbbb2', 'type': 'cccc2', 'product_url': 'url2'}]
```

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I want.  I didn't know all() function.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have an outer loop that loops over each element in the list `my_dicts` and to have an inner loop that loops over each element of a given dict.  For a given iteration of the outer loop, we store the index of the dict inside `my_dicts` inside the `indices` list if one of the values in the dict is contained in `my_list`. After completing our scan over `my_dicts`, using the indices we know which elements of `my_dicts` to remove.

```
indices = []
# locate dicts with a value that is in my_list
for index, elem in enumerate(my_dicts):
    for key in elem:
        if elem[key] in my_list:
            indices.append(index)
            break 
# remove dicts 
for i in reversed(indices):
    my_dicts.pop(i)

print(my_dicts)
```

Output

```
[{'name': 'aaa2', 'codename': 'bbbb2', 'type': 'cccc2', 'product_url': 'url2'}]
```

I hope this helps!